# How to get x number of days from today?

Tags: c#, date

I'm trying to take today's date and find a date x number of days in the future. So, for example, I want to find the date 30 days from now - what library should I look into using for this?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx (this is a RTFM comment)

Comment: DateTime.Now.AddDays(30)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx)  and [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) structure.

```
DateTime in30Days = DateTime.Today.AddDays(30);
```

or

```
TimeSpan days30 = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
DateTime in30Days = DateTime.Today + days30;
```

If you need need `DateTime` and time-period calculations heavily, you should have a look at the [Time Period library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET) (open license) which i can recommend.

Answer (score 2):

use `DateTime`

```
DateTime _x = DateTime.Today.AddDays(30);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a library, the .NET DateTime struct has all you need.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx for an explanation and example!

Comment: It's DateTime, it's a struct, and I would argue that it's severely lacking in general, although it will suffice for this specific requirement...

Answer (score 0):

System.DateTime is the struct you need.

Examples:

```
DateTime.Today.AddDays(30); //30 days forwards
DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30); //30 days backwards.
```

Comment: Its not a namespace its a struct.