# Using LINQ in C#, How to retrieve list of events based on specific dates, for example all events that are planned for upcoming 45 days?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am working on this Linq query and it retrieves the list of items from database that are planned for any dates which are greater than the current date.

```
var todolist = from i in _context.ActPlan
                       where i.Expected_Date > DateTime.Now
                       select i;
```

But i want to retrieve list of the items that are planned for the upcoming 45 days only (all items between the current date and till the upcoming 45 days) but certainly not all future events.

Comment: What about https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.adddays?view=netframework-4.7.2 ?

Comment: `var todolist = _context.ActPlan.Where(x => x.Expected_Date > DateTime.Today && x.Expected_Date < DateTime.Today + 45)` This is not valid syntax but should give you an idea

Comment: `var fromDate = DateTime.UtcNow; var toDate = fromDate.AddDays(45); ... where i.Expected_Date >= fromDate && i.Expected_Date < toDate ...`

Comment: @Matt you can't use '+' operator on `DateTime` and `int`

Comment: @Florian your method gives this error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddDays(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @JohnKamaal Do the `AddDays` calc on the previous line of code and assign it to a variable called `bob`. Then use `bob` inside your LINQ query.

Comment: @Florian I said it wasn't valid syntax, it was just to get the idea of what to do.

Comment: @JohnKamaal You can use `System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddDays`within a LINQ to Entities query instead of `System.DateTime.AddDays`, which can't be used

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get x number of days from today?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928547/how-to-get-x-number-of-days-from-today)

Comment: @Matt: you are mixing int and DateTime types, it's not about *syntax*....

Comment: @Florian Ok, sure.

Comment: @JohnKamaal the answer has been updated and should now work. The error you had is because Linq can't translate to valid SQL the method `System.DateTime.AddDays` as ZippyZippedUp said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `AddDays` method (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.adddays?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
DateTime inFortyFiveDays = DateTime.Now.AddDays(45);
var toDoList = (from i in _context.ActPlan where 
                               i.Expected_Date > DateTime.Now &&
                               i.Expected_Date < inFortyFiveDays
                select i)
```

Comment: And if you get an error on the AddDays, precalculate that enddate in a separate variable and use that

Comment: @HansKeﬆing : how  `DateTime.Now.AddDays(x)` (where x is an int) can throw ArgumentOutOfRangeException ?

Comment: @Florian for example if your `x` is `int.MaxValue`.

Comment: @SeM : obviously yes, here it is 45, so I don't understand hans comment.

Comment: @Florian I think Hans is saying that if used within the LINQ statement, DateTime.Now.AddDays will throw an error because LINQ to Entities does not support that method, so the value must be calculated and stored in a variable outside of the LINQ statement as he showed in his example.

Comment: @akerra Yes, that is what I meant. And I see Florian has updated the sample code

Comment: @Florian check this if you get time, thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53802276/in-a-single-razor-view-how-can-i-retrieve-values-passed-from-different-methods/53802398#53802398